# react native firebase setBackgroundMessageHandler invoked just in forground

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I have a react native app and installed react native app & messaging, and can receive notifications, but what i need is incoming call notification, so i implemented handler to first catch the notification when app is closed, but even my log not appear in console and device just shows nodification and get fired when app is in forground, why is that?

```
.
.
.
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Answer (score 0):

If want to see foreground notification messages then you have to use onMessage listener

**Foreground state messages**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      Alert.alert('A new FCM message arrived!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
}
```

**Background & Quit state messages**

**Important note**: To setup a background handler, call the setBackgroundMessageHandler outside of your application logic as early as possible

```
// index.js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import App from './App';

// Register background handler
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('app', () => App);
```

Comment: thank you, it seems my code works, but now i don't know how to launch app, tries RNCallKeep.displayIncomingCall, but didnt worked

Comment: So you want to show the incoming call in the background notification handler?

Comment: yes, using callKeep, backToForground didn'd worked, also displayIncomingCall!

Comment: Ok i haven't worked with call keep plugin but i had opened app from background mode in notification background handler using [react-native-invoke-app](https://github.com/vicke4/react-native-invoke-app)

Comment: thank you, but i dont know why its not working, using that library can be an alternative, do you think it might be because of 'SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW' permission in android 10+

Comment: @kingofday I don't think so `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission is used to show  window even if your app is not open.

Answer (score -1):

my issue was that i test it with fcm tester, notification must be data only type to not be shown